# LWJGL Qubes to Big

Tags: java, lwjgl

For school i want to make a game. So i decided to make something like the game Minecraft.

If i draw a for example the front face of my cube like this:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(0f,0f,0f);
glVertex3f(0f,1f,0f);
glVertex3f(1f,1f,0f);
glVertex3f(1f,0f,0f);
glEnd();
```

The Rectangle is way to big. So instead of using 1f is must use something like 0.0001f. So the positions are more difficult for me to calculate.

am i doing something wrong or is there a way to make everything smaller as it is at the moment (by changeing something in the perspective or so) ?

sorry for that silly question i'm new to lwjgl and opengl.

Comment: You do realize that any vertices with less than 1.0f as a position value will have space in between the next cube right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cubes can't be too big, everything is relative.
If you look at the 1.0f x 1.0f rectangre from the distance of 1.0f, it will be big. While looking from the 100.0f you will see a little spot.
Just learn how to set a camera position and use perspective projection.
Perspective projection example:

```
GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GLU.gluPerspective(90f, Display.getWidth() / Display.getHeight(), 0.1f, 5000f);
```

Camera position example:

```
GLU.gluLookAt(x, y, z, viewX, viewY, viewZ, upX, upY, upZ);
```

Also you should learn what is up vector.

Answer (score 0):

I see there being two options for your problem.

- You could take all the ones from your glVertex3f and multiply them by a decimal number in order to scale them down
- or you could try using GL11.glScalef(x, y, z) this should scale the coordinates you pass in by the x, y, and z values specified in this method. You can call this method before you begin to draw your cube.

Hop this helps.